# (Short) - POST data should be bytes or an iterable of bytes. It cannot be of type str

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Just trying to feed-in links from a .csv file, then scrape info from each link, then write it to other columns in the .csv. I've been scratching my head for days. Can anyone else see what's wrong here? The error happens at `soup`

```
def scrape_data(csv_file):
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
reader = csv.reader(csv_file)  

for row in reader:
    if row:

        # THE ERROR HAPPENS AT THE SOUP OBJECT BELOW            

        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(row[0], 'lxml'))
        post_time = soup.find('time', {'class' : 'date timeago'})            
        sqfeet = (sqft.text for sqft in soup.find('span', {'class' : 'shared-line-bubble'})) 
        availability = (soup.find('span', {'class' : 'data-date'}))            
        attribute_group = (ag.text for ag in soup.find('p', {'class' : 'attrgroup'}))
        address = (add.text for add in soup.find('div', {'class' : 'mapaddress'}))            

        for data in zip(post_time, sqfeet, availability, attribute_group, address):
            writer.writerow(row[3])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'lxml'` part must be a parameter of `BeautifulSoup()` but is parameter of `urllib.request.urlopen()`